# Rails controller handling discrepancy development/production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

> Summary: in development, requests are routed to `workouts_controller.rb` but in production to `workouts_controllerPrev.rb`

In a Rails 5.2.3 app, I have the file `workouts_controller.rb` in the `controllers/` folder with first line:

```
WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
```

I took a copy of `workouts_controller.rb` (to serve as a quick reference backup) which I renamed to `workouts_controllerPrev.rb` and retained in the `controllers/` folder.

I then introduced some new functionality to `workouts_controller.rb`. I tested the new functionality locally (it worked as expected in development) and then I deployed to Heroku (v 7.42.0) (for production).

The new functionality, however didn’t work in production. After some debugging, I identified that in production, the `WorkoutsController class` in `workouts_controllerPrev.rb` was handling calls to the `Workouts controller` (rather than the `Workouts controller` defined in `workouts_controller.rb` (as anticipated and as happening in development).

I made a more dramatic name change to `workouts_controllerPrev.rb`, changing it to `Xwurkouts_controllerPrev.rb`, and changed the class name in this file to `XWurkoutsController` redeployed and it all worked fine.

What is happening here? Why would Rails function  differently in this respect between the 2 environments? Is this a bug or an unsurprising consequence of a bad practice of having unused files loitering around? If a bug, where should I report it?
I am using SQLite in development, and PostGreSQL in production, but I don’t see this can be a database issue? The production webserver is Puma.

Thanks for any guidance

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that both files have the same *class* name in them, so the actions (methods) in whichever one is loaded *last* will override the actions defined in the one loaded *first*.

If you want to keep both files around and not have surprising results, change the *class* name in the old file to something else like `PrevWorkoutsController`.

Or, save it in a branch in Git so it doesn't clutter your current code.

---

To answer about why you got different results in different environments, it is because of the difference between autoloading vs. eager loading. Rails uses *autoloading* in development, but it *eager loads* everything up front in production, then turns autoloading *off*.

In other words, in development, Rails will reload the class from its matching file any time that file is saved. In production, it simply loads *all* files up front, so whichever one it loads last will win.

You can [read more here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants_classic_mode.html#autoload-paths-and-eager-load-paths).

Comment: you're quite right @rmhunter, I omitted to mention that my solution involved changing the class name as well as the file name (and based upon your response it was the change in class name that was key). I will edit my question accordingly. This still leaves the unanswered question why is there a disparity between the 2 environments...?

Comment: @DanSimBed I added to my answer explaining, and included a link to read more :)

Comment: make the hours of debugging almost seem worthwhile when you learn something useful at the end of it! Many thanks @rmhunter